# Как добавить данные в документ mongodb?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

Сайт React, Node, Mongodb. К примеру, есть три страницы с формами.
Получая данные на первой странице, данные отправляются на сервер обрабатываются и записываются в бд (создаётся новый документ в коллекции), переход к следующей странице. На второй странице так же получаем данные отправляем на сервер и.....
Как добавить данные именно в тот документ который был создан?
Как за каждым пользователем закрепить документ из коллекции mongodb?

Comment: При создании схемы ты можешь указывать `data: [{ type: Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]` так ты добавляешь ссылку на объект на который ты хочешь ссылаться. Проще говоря ты привязываешь данные к пользователю. Если ты хочешь получить данные по ObjectId пользователя тебе поможет метод populate. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html. Тоже самое если тебе нужно обновить данные.

Comment: Да с этим получилось, но потом я что то поменял и не могу опять придти к тому как было))))))))
не могу понять как обратится к тому документу который был создан при первом запросе..